# Using "if let..." with many expressions

Tags: swift

This idiom of Swift makes good sense

```
if let x = someDict[someKey] { ... }
```

However, what I *really* want is

```
if let x = someDict[someKey], y = someDict[someOtherKey] { ... }
```

As written this is not incorrect, but is this idea possible?

Comment: Does `let x = someDict[someKey], y = someDict[someOtherKey]` not work? It actually looks like correct syntax, according to Swift language reference. Or are you looking for a more concise way to combine multiple expressions?

Comment: Are you looking for another answer than those already provided? If not, can you accept one please?

Comment: Note that as of Swift 1.2, just released this week, you can do this using your proposed syntax.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update for Swift 1.2**

Since Swift 1.2, `if let` allows unwrapping multiple optionals, so you can now just write this, as in your example:

```
if let x = someDict[someKey], y = someDict[someOtherKey] { … }
```

You can even interleave conditions such as:

```
if let x = someDict[someKey] where x == "value", y = someDict[someOtherKey] { … }
```

---

**This used to be valid before Swift 1.2**

Here's how you would do it without an ugly force-upwrapping:

```
switch (dict["a"], dict["b"]) {
case let (.Some(a), .Some(b)):
    println("match")
default:
    println("no match")
}
```

Still pretty verbose, actually.

This works because an optional type of the form `Type?` is actually shorthand for `Optional<Type>`, which is an enum that looks roughly like this:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
}
```

You can then use pattern matching as for any other enum.

**Edit:** I've seen people write helper functions like this one (sorry for the lack of attribution, I don't remember where I saw it):

```
func unwrap<A, B>(a: A?, b: B?) -> (A, B)? {
    switch (a, b) {
    case let (.Some(a), .Some(b)):
        return (a, b)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then you can keep using the `if let` construct, namely like this:

```
if let (a, b) = unwrap(dict["a"], dict["b"]) {
    println("match: \(a), \(b)")
} else {
    println("no match")
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does? I don't really understand the `.Some` part.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: `.Some` means anything that's not `.None` -- i.e., the value exists. You still have to typecast it later if you care about its actual type: `case (.Some(let a as NSString), .Some(let b as NSString)):`

Comment: No, it infers the type from the static type of `dict`.

Comment: You can (slightly) shorten this using `case let (.Some(a), .Some(b)):`

Comment: I didn't know about the `where` part of a `let` in a `if`; it helped me very much!

Comment: interleave conditions example after swift 1.2, the where condition should be after `y = someDict[someOtherKey]`, or you add another `let` before `y = someDict[someOtherKey]`.

Comment: Swift 3.0

if let latitudeDouble = latitude as? Double, let longitudeDouble = longitude as? Double {
    // do stuff here
}

Answer (score 4):

In [Swift 1.2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) (part of Xcode 6.3), the [`if let` optional binding construct can bind multiple optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333), using the same syntax found in this question.

```
if let x = someDict[someKey], y = someDict[someOtherKey] { ... }
```

You can also extend this with conditions on the bound values:

```
if let a = foo(), b = bar(), a < b, let c = baz() { ... }
```

The `switch` pattern for handling multiple-optional binding (as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120687/957768)) remains valid. Although with `if let` guard conditions you might find fewer use cases for it, it's still there in case you want to, say, handle cases of multiple optional binding with different behavior when different subsets of the optionals you're testing are nil.

(Note: Prior to Swift 3, `if let a = ..., b = ..., a < b` used `where` to split the binding from the conditional.)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift1.2,you could use multiple optional bindings.

```
if let x = someDict[someKey], y = someDict[someOtherKey] { ... }
```

Notice that y is implicitly declared as constant,which is the same as x.The above code is equivalent to the following.

```
if let x = someDict[someKey],let y = someDict[someOtherKey] { ... }
```

If you want to explicitly declare y as mutable type,just type var before the variable name.

```
if let x = someDict[someKey],var y = someDict[someOtherKey] { ... }
```