# unwrapping multiple optionals in if statement

Tags: swift, option-type

I want to unwrap two optionals in one if statement, but the compiler complaints about an expected expression after operator at the password constant.
What could be the reason?

```
    if let email = self.emailField?.text && let password = self.passwordField?.text
    {
        //do smthg
    }
```

Done in Swift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "if let..." with many expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118900/using-if-let-with-many-expressions)

Comment: Just a quick comment - learning Swift myself and my "instinct" was to put "&&". You asked the question much more concisely than I what I was googling. Thanks!

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Great news. Unwrapping multiple optionals in a single line is now supported in **Swift 1.2** (XCode 6.3 beta, released 2/9/15).

No more tuple/switch pattern matching needed. It's actually very close to your original suggested syntax (thanks for listening, Apple!)

```
if let email = emailField?.text, password = passwordField?.text {

}
```

Another nice thing is you can also add `where` for a "guarding condition":

```
var email: String? = "baz@bar.com"
var name: String? = "foo"

if let n = name, e = email where contains(e, "@") {
  println("name and email exist, email has @")
}
```

Reference: [XCode 6.3 Beta Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta/Xcode_6.3_beta_Release_Notes.pdf)

Comment: Why would theey ever choose to use a comma (,) instead of &&. For the love of Swift please stop the madness!

Comment: It's a comma because it's a list of declared variables. Just like `let a=0, b=1` on it's own line. && and || etc are logical operators. You can still use them in the condition itself: `if let a=0, b=1 where a < b && b > 0`

Comment: Should add `let` in swift 3 for each optional.

Answer (score 46):

Update for Swift 3:

```
if let email = emailField?.text, let password = passwordField?.text {
}
```

each variable must now be preceded by a *let* keyword

Answer (score 25):

How about wrapping the optionals in a tuple and using *switch* to pattern match?

```
switch (self.emailField?.text, self.passwordField?.text) {
case let (.Some(email), .Some(password)):
    // unwrapped 'email' and 'password' strings available here
default:
    break
}
```

It's definitely a bit noisier, but at least it could also be combined with a *where* clause as well.

Comment: `case let (.Some(email as NSString), .Some(password as NSString)):`

Comment: Well that is actually even more verbose than typing out an `if`, so what would be the point?

Comment: @ErikAigner I think this was actually written before Swift allowed you to unwrap multiple optionals in the same `if let` statement. Came with Swift 1.2 :)

Answer (score 9):

The usage

```
if let x = y {
}
```

is not equivalent to

```
if (let x = y) { // this is actually not allowed
}
```

"if let" is effectively a two-word keyword, which is equivalent to

```
if y != nil {
    let x = y!
    // rest of if let block
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Before Swift 1.2**

Like @James, I've also created an `unwrap` function, but this one uses the existing `if let` for control flow, instead of using a closure:

```
func unwrap<T1, T2>(optional1: T1?, optional2: T2?) -> (T1, T2)? {
  switch (optional1, optional2) {
  case let (.Some(value1), .Some(value2)):
    return (value1, value2)
  default:
    return nil
  }
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
if let (email, password) = unwrap(self.emailField?.text, self.passwordField?.text)
{
  // do something
}
```

From: https://gist.github.com/tomlokhorst/f9a826bf24d16cb5f6a3

Note that if you want to handle more cases (like when one of the two fields *is* nil), you're better off with a `switch` statement.

Comment: This can be overloaded too. unwrap<A, B, C>(a: A?, b: B?, c: C?) -> (A, B, C)?

Comment: @DaveLee Yes, as the gist shows, you can have multiple overloads for `unwrap`. However these do need to be defined manually, it is not possible to define one version for the different types.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
if let suggestions = suggestions, let suggestions1 = suggestions1 {

        XCTAssert((suggestions.count > suggestions1.count), "TEST CASE FAILED: suggestion is nil. delete sucessful");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why the above code doesn't work, but this would be good a replacement:

```
if let email = self.emailField?.text 
{
    if let password = self.passwordField?.text 
    {
        //do smthg
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Joel's answer, I've created a helper method.

```
func unwrap<T, U>(a:T?, b:U?, handler:((T, U) -> ())?) -> Bool {
    switch (a, b) {
    case let (.Some(a), .Some(b)):
        if handler != nil {
            handler!(a, b)
        }
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

// Usage

```
unwrap(a, b) {
    println("\($0), \($1)")
}
```