# Unwrapping and checking multiple optionals on single line

Tags: ios, swift

I currently use this pattern

```
do {

    if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

        let valid: Int? = 1
        let status: String? = "ok"

            if let v = jsonResult["valid"] as? Int, s = jsonResult["status"] as? String {
                if v == valid && s == status{
                //Do something
                }
            }
    }
```

Is this the optimal method to check that v == 1 and s == "ok"

Or is it possible to do something like this answer, would it be better ?
[Answer(Unwrapping multiple optionals in a single line)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418847)

```
if let v = jsonResult["valid"] as? Int, s = jsonResult["status"] as? String 
   where is(v, valid && s, status)
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you planning on using `v` and `s` inside the body of the `if`, or are they just for comparing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need `v` and `s` inside of the body of the `if`, you can just do the comparison directly:

```
if jsonResult["valid"] as? Int == 1 && jsonResult["status"] as? String == "ok" {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try guard statement 
something like this

```
let dict = NSDictionary()

dict.setValue(Int(1), forKey: "one")
dict.setValue("String", forKey: "two")

guard let one = dict["one"] as? Int, two = dict["two"] as? String where one == 1 && two == "String" else  {
    print ("no")
    return
}

print ("one is \(one) two is \(two)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if let v = jsonResult["valid"] as? Int, s = jsonResult["status"] as? String where (v == valid && s == status) {}
```