# Avoid consecutive "if let" declarations in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift I used `if let` declarations to check if my object is not `nil`

```
if let obj = optionalObj
{
}
```

But sometimes, I have to face with consecutive `if let` declarations

```
if let obj = optionalObj
{
    if let a = obj.a
    {
        if let b = a.b
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to avoid consecutive `if let` declarations.

I would try something like :

```
if let obj = optionalObj && if let a = obj.a && if let b = a.b
{
    // do stuff
}
```

But the swift compiler do not allow this.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. I have a JSON dictionary, and I need to get 5 keys out of it. Right now, I have a nested 5-level deep `if let` block, and I don't much like it.

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592004/using-multiple-let-as-within-a-if-statement-in-swift.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: You're right, I deleted my previous comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a little essay on the alternatives some time ago: https://gist.github.com/pyrtsa/77978129090f6114e9fb

One approach not yet mentioned in the other answers, which I kinda like, is to add a bunch of overloaded `every` functions:

```
func every<A, B>(a: A?, b: B?) -> (A, B)? {
    switch (a, b) {
        case let (.Some(a), .Some(b)): return .Some((a, b))
        default:                       return .None
    }
}

func every<A, B, C>(a: A?, b: B?, c: C?) -> (A, B, C)? {
    switch (a, b, c) {
        case let (.Some(a), .Some(b), .Some(c)): return .Some((a, b, c))
        default:                                 return .None
    }
}

// and so on...
```

These can be used in `if let` statements, `case` expressions, as well as `optional.map(...)` chains:

```
// 1.
var foo: Foo?
if let (name, phone) = every(parsedName, parsedPhone) {
    foo = ...
}

// 2.
switch every(parsedName, parsedPhone) {
    case let (name, phone): foo = ...
    default: foo = nil
}

// 3.
foo = every(parsedName, parsedPhone).map{name, phone in ...}
```

Having to add the overloads for `every` is boilerplate'y but only has to be done in a library once. Similarly, with the Applicative Functor approach (i.e. using the `<^>` and `<*>` operators), you'd need to create the curried functions somehow, which causes a bit of boilerplate somewhere too.

Comment: But indeed, for the exact example in question, you should use optional chaining.

Comment: Nice workaround, your solution looks like the answer I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26673138/2754218

Comment: @JeanLebrument Sure, it just avoids the callback "handler" block, which I think is a separate concern that `Optional.map` already solves for you.

Comment: Is there a way to create a method `every` with variadic parameters?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you probably won't need many overloads of it.

Comment: A last question, is there an operator which is commonly used to unwrap object ? It's would be cleaner that using a method name.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can derive every from a pair formation operator and the applicative stuff Gabrielle mentions.  `every2` is `liftA2 (,)`, `every3` is `liftA3 (,,)`

Comment: I'm not sure of the meaning of your comment ? You're saying that I can overload a tuple operator to permits the unwrapping ?

Comment: As CodaFi mentions, the `every` implementation can be built on top of my answer, if you like. Once we have the Applicative machinery in place, the rest is just clever syntax ;)

Comment: @CodaFi Yeah, the applicative lifts and tuple constructors are an even more fundamental building block for it. We still have to spell out all the arities, though (a restriction even Haskell doesn't remove without Template Haskell). If only the Swift standard had the generic functions of type `<A, B>(A) -> B -> (A, B)`, `<A, B, C>(A) -> B -> C -> (A, B, C)` etc. :)

Comment: @pyrtsa I heard you liked tuple packing.  [I know a guy that can help](https://github.com/typelift/Basis/blob/f6505409c5bf8f81148202d40a1063b667a2876c/Basis/Tuple.swift#L55-L128)

Comment: This is overkill since swift 1.2

Answer (score 27):

### Update

In swift 1.2 you can do

```
if let a = optA, let b = optB {
  doStuff(a, b)
}
```

---

### Original answer

In your specific case, you can use optional chaining:

```
if let b = optionaObj?.a?.b {
  // do stuff
}
```

---

Now, if you instead need to do something like

```
if let a = optA {
  if let b = optB {
    doStuff(a, b)
  }
}
```

you're out of luck, since you can't use optional chaining.

### tl; dr

Would you prefer a cool one-liner instead?

```
doStuff <^> optA <*> optB
```

Keep reading. For how scaring it might look, this is really powerful and not so crazy to use as it seems.

Fortunately, this is a problem easily solved using a functional programming approach. You can use the `Applicative` abstraction and provide an `apply` method for composing multiple options together.

Here's an example, taken from http://robots.thoughtbot.com/functional-swift-for-dealing-with-optional-values

First we need a function to apply a function to an optional value only only when it contains something

```
// this function is usually called fmap, and it's represented by a <$> operator
// in many functional languages, but <$> is not allowed by swift syntax, so we'll
// use <^> instead
infix operator <^> { associativity left }

func <^><A, B>(f: A -> B, a: A?) -> B? {
    switch a {
    case .Some(let x): return f(x)
    case .None: return .None
    }
}
```

Then we can compose multiple options together using apply, which we'll call `<*>` because we're cool (and we know some Haskell)

```
// <*> is the commonly-accepted symbol for apply
infix operator <*> { associativity left }

func <*><A, B>(f: (A -> B)?, a: A?) -> B? {
    switch f {
    case .Some(let value): return value <^> a
    case .None: return .None
    }
}
```

Now we can rewrite our example

```
doStuff <^> optA <*> optB
```

This will work, provided that `doStuff` is in curried form (see below), i.e.

```
func doStuff(a: A)(b: B) -> C { ... }
```

The result of the whole thing is an optional value, either `nil` or the result of `doStuff`

Here's a complete example that you can try in the playground

```
func sum(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int { return a + b }

let optA: Int? = 1
let optB: Int? = nil
let optC: Int? = 2

sum <^> optA <*> optB // nil
sum <^> optA <*> optC // Some 3
```

---

As a final note, it's really straightforward to convert a function to its curried form. For instance if you have a function taking two parameters:

```
func curry<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C {
    return { a in { b in f(a,b) } }
}
```

Now you can curry any two-parameter function, like `+` for example

```
curry(+) <^> optA <*> optC // Some 3
```

Comment: This may seem like a complicated answer but IMHO it's the correct way to think about the solution. We shouldn't just do line ports of our Objective-C code.

Comment: Would a monadic bind be another way to approach this: http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-culmination-part-ii ? It wouldn't require currying of the end function, but would still need if-let, etc. to handle the optional returned from the process.

Comment: @BradLarson oh yes, a monadic bind is definitely a valid approach and I use it extensively in other languages. However I have two concerns: monads are much more powerful than applicatives, and I usually tend to prefer the least powerful abstraction; second, swift lacks the syntactic sugar provided by do-blocks (haskell) or for-blocks (scala), so it's arguably more cumbersome to use than applicative. Both are valid approaches nevertheless :)

Comment: Does `for {} yeld {}` is already available on Swift ? Because, the compiler on xCode 6.1 throw me an error.

Comment: @JeanLebrument it's not, which is kind of my point in the above comment. Syntax support is not ready for monadic binding

Comment: nice. now you have a language that totally defeats its simplification purpose

Comment: also, the optional chaining syntax hints at something like `if optA? && optB?` like in coffeescript, yet apparently that would not work?

Comment: @njzk2 care to explain what you mean?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: I though swift was introduced to provide a modern language that would result in simpler code. Apparently I was mistaken, as I don't think redefining operators according to haskell conventions qualifies as simpler code.

Comment: @njk2 swift is modern enough the able to use express powerful abstractions, such as Applicative. Nobody is redefining anything, simply we can solve the same problem other languages have faced before in a similar fashion. The code is simple, and familiar to any functional programmer but of course it's a matter of taste. Nesting ifs might be easier to read for a new-comer, although not so simple. Again simplicity and ease are two different things. It can be hard to achieve simple code, but it's often worth it

Comment: Beautiful.  fmap.  Gawd.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you can use optional chaining.  For your simple example:

```
if let b = optionalObj?.a?.b {
    // do stuff
}
```

To keep your nesting down and to give yourself the same variable assignments, you could also do this:

```
if optionalObj?.a?.b != nil {
    let obj = optionalObj!
    let a = obj.a!
    let b = a.b!
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but in my case, I need to have a reference of each of my objects.

Answer (score 1):

After some lecture thanks to Martin R, I found an interesting workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012746/2754218

```
func unwrap<T, U>(a:T?, b:U?, handler:((T, U) -> ())?) -> Bool {
    switch (a, b) {
    case let (.Some(a), .Some(b)):
        if handler != nil {
            handler!(a, b)
        }
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

The solution is interesting, but it would be better if the method uses variadic parameters.

I naively started to create such a method:

```
extension Array
{
    func find(includedElement: T -> Bool) -> Int?
    {
        for (idx, element) in enumerate(self)
        {
            if includedElement(element)
            {
                return idx
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}

func unwrap<T>(handler:((T...) -> Void)?, a:T?...) -> Bool
{

    let b : [T!] = a.map { $0 ?? nil}

    if b.find({ $0 == nil }) == nil
    {
        handler(b)
    }
}
```

But I've this error with the compiler: `Cannot convert the expression's type '[T!]' to type '((T...) -> Void)?'`

Any suggestion for a workaround ?

Comment: Try asking this as a separate question.