# Unwrapping multiple Swift optionals

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm trying to rewrite part of ObjC code with Swift, a lot of cocoa object properties return optional value in Swift. Is there better pattern instead of this deep nesting:

```
  if let panel = self.window {
     if let screens = NSScreen.screens() {
        if  let screenRect = screens[0].frame {
           let statusRect = CGRectZero
              ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift optional binding with tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991378/swift-optional-binding-with-tuples)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548999/unwrapping-multiple-optionals-in-if-statement/25048307#25048307

Comment: @AlexBrown Sorry, I don't think either of those questions is exactly identical to this one. The questioner is talking about a chain of optionals. Take a look at some of the answers below. (I don't doubt, though, that this question is a dupe of some other one, just not the ones you linked.)

Comment: Yes, I saw that helpers before, but the problem with these helper methods is that they return tupples of fixed length. So we need several of them for deeper nesting, depending of depth.

Comment: I don't know why you say it's a chain of optionals - the evidence is ambiguous - the first line is not part of a chain with the second and third.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671833/avoid-consecutive-if-let-declarations-in-swift/26673847#26673847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Leonardo's answer is a good one, it can lead to exceptions unless you know the objects are non-optional, a better pattern is this, which should be regarded as pseudocode:

```
if let frame = NSScreen.screens()?.first?.frame {
   // Do something with frame.
}
```

In other words, use optional chaining (`?.`), but only use `let` with the very last part of the chain.

You could also create an operator like this if you want to chain optionals that are of a different type, in which only the value of the last one will be returned:

```
infix operator ??? { associativity left }

func ??? <T1, T2>(t1: T1?, t2: @autoclosure () -> T2?) -> T2? {
    return t1 == nil ? nil : t2()
}

if let frame = self.window ??? NSScreen.screens()?.first?.frame {
    // Do something with frame
}
```

This is, of course, inspired by Haskell's bind. But as fun as this is, I don't recommend it. I think it's clear as mud. (By the way, the difference between `???` and `??` is that the former does *not* require the lhs and rhs to be of the same type (or supertype), while the latter does. `???` always returns its rhs or `nil`.)

Comment: @AlexBrown link above has good points and detailed explanations, but this answer is the most elegant. The only downside of this is that you don't know which one of the steps failed.

Comment: If you care about which steps failed, don't use this approach. Instead, use combinations of `?.` and `if let`.

Comment: Finished porting code, anyway, I found unwrapping multiple Swift optionals  annoying and ugly to read. Sometimes i.e: if let statusItemView = statusItem?.view as? StatusItemView when you need casting you're unable to continue chain and forced to nesting. A lot of cocoa properties are  rewritten as optional values and it looks like temporary solution to ensure avoiding nil and keep compatibility with ObjC. Looks to me that Swift code readability isn't so good when used with current cocoa framework.

Comment: @SinisaDrpa I agree. This is an artifact of going from a weakly typed dynamic language to a strongly typed static one.

Answer (score 1):

You can force unwrap it like this:

```
NSScreen.screens()!.first!.frame!
NSScreen.screens()!.first!.frame!.width
NSScreen.screens()!.first!.frame!.height


// safely unwraping it as required an mentioned by Gregory
if let frame = NSScreen.screens()?.first?.frame {
    println(frame)
}
if let width = NSScreen.screens()?.first?.frame?.width {
    println(width)
}
if let height = NSScreen.screens()?.first?.frame?.height {
    println(height)
}
```

Comment: It's unsafe, will cause crash if one of the values is nil.

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a blog post](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/12/08/swift-optional-pyramids-of-doom.html) a while back which explored a few different ways to unwrap multiple optionals.

You can create a function that unwraps multiple optionals in one go:

```
func if_let<T, U, V>(a: Optional<T>, b: Optional<U>,
  c: Optional<V>, fn: (T, U, V) -> ()) {
  if let a = a {
    if let b = b {
      if let c = c {
        fn(a, b, c)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

used as follows:

```
if_let(a, b, c) {
  a, b, c in
  println("\(a) - \(b) - \(c)")
}
```

Someone also proposed a neat solution using tuples, that can be [found in this gist](https://gist.github.com/tomlokhorst/f9a826bf24d16cb5f6a3).

Comment: I found it before, great post. The only downside is as you said there is no way to use different num. of params. we need multiple versions of the same for 2,3 ... nested optionals.

Comment: @SinisaDrpa very true, the same applies to all of the other techniques I have seen for achieving this. We can only wait and hope for better language support!

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 1.2 you can do unwrapping on one line, as described in this answer:

[unwrapping multiple optionals in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548999/unwrapping-multiple-optionals-in-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Please read about optional chaining here:
[Linking Multiple Levels of Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID252)

And you can play with this playground to look how does it work:

```
import UIKit


class AAA {
    var string: String? = nil
}

class AA {
    var aaa: [AAA?]? = nil
}

class A {
    var aa: AA? = nil
}


var a: A?

a = A()

/// Comment/Uncomment next lines
a?.aa = AA()
//a?.aa?.aaa = [AAA()]
a?.aa?.aaa = []
a?.aa?.aaa?.first??.string = "My String Value"

if let myString = a?.aa?.aaa?.first??.string {
    print("myString: \(myString)")
} else {
    print("myString does not acceptable")
}
```

And your code may look like:

```
if let panel = self.window, let statusRect = NSScreen.screens()?.first??.frame ?? CGRect.zero {
    /// your code to work with panel and statusRect
}
```