# Swift optional binding with tuples

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I'm trying to use a tuple as an optional binding in an IF statement in Swift but it won't compile and that error message is less than helpful.  Why doesn't the following compile?

```
let user:String? = "billy"
let pass:String? = "password"

if let test = (user?,pass?){
    print("this works")
}
```

or this

```
let user:String? = "billy"
let pass:String? = "password"

if let test = (user,pass){
    print("this works")
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error? If I had to guess, it's because the creation of a tuple doesn't produce a result optionally.

Comment: Do you actually want to bind the tuple, or do you just want to bind two optionals in the same statement? If the latter, this is a duplicate of [Using “if let…” with many expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24118900/957768), which has a concise solution as of Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3.

Answer (score 19):

edit: as of Swift 1.2 in Xcode 6.3, you can now do:

```
if let user = user, pass = pass { }
```

to bind multiple unwrapped optional values.

You can't use optional let binding that way.  `let test = (user,pass)` won't compile since `(user,pass)` is not an optional – it's a tuple that *contains* optionals.  That is, it's an `(Int?,Int?)` not an `(Int,Int)?`.

This should do what you want and allows you to bind two items simultaneously:

```
switch (user, pass) {
    case let (.Some(user), .Some(pass)):
        print("this works: \(user), \(pass)")
    default: ()  // must handle all cases
}
```

Comment: You can use `break` in switch statement cases with no code, it seems more coherent to me.

Comment: Good point that is probably nicer. Though I've never found myself needing no default (and in fact would love switch statements to be expressions in which case you'd have to have one return a meaningful value).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your suggestion.  What is the ".Some( )"  It looks like an enumeration member with an associated value. Where does it come from and how its it working in this case?

Comment: You are spot on, that’s exactly what it is.  That’s what optionals are – enumerations with two cases, `Some` and `None`, and the `Some` case has an associated value of type `T`.  You can even see the definition for them in the standard library – try typing `Optional(5)` into a playground and cmd-opt-click the word optional.

Comment: There's a let missing in the provided answer.  It should be:
if let usr = user, let ps = pass { }

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 2 with optional pattern matching you can write

```
if case let (user?, pass?) = (user, pass) { }
```

This is especially useful if, for example, (user, pass) is a tuple stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `switch` as the other answer points out. However, **if you're only going to check both values**, an `if` **without** Optional Binding is actually shorter and easier-to-read.

```
if (user != nil && pass != nil) {
    print("this works: \(user!), \(pass!)")
}
```

The `switch` is goofy and hard-to-read (taken from other answer), but if you're going to use the other cases (nil-some, some-nil, nil-nil) then it might be worth it.

```
switch (user, pass) {
    case let (.Some(user), .Some(pass)): print("this works: \(user), \(pass)")
    default: ()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if case let (.some(user), .some(pass)) = (optionalUser, optionalPass) {
    print("user \(user). pass \(pass)")
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you added an explanation of the code

Answer (score -1):

Let's say we have tuple having two optional Ints. To unwrap it we can optionally cast it to (Int, Int) using as?. If any of them is nil then it won't be able to cast it. If it does we will get unwrapped values from that tuple.

```
let tuple: (Int?, Int?) = (1, 2)
if let (value1, value2) = tuple as? (Int, Int) {
     print("value1: \(value1), value2: \(value2)")
} 

//value1: 1, value2: 2
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.