# Swift error while returning multiple values from function

Tags: swift, function

I can not understand what I did wrong

---

I have an app which loads posts and its comments. The view controller requests a function from an another file, which returns back (response?, comments?)

I get one error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '(ActionResult?, [PostComment]?)'

For the line

```
if let (response, comments) = (response, comments )
```

What did I wrong?

**commentsViewController**

```
postComments.loadCommentForPost(id: postId) { (response, comments) in
            // ERROR here: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '(ActionResult?, [WorldMessageComment]?)'
            if let (response, comments) = (response, comments ) {
                if response!.success == 1 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                            self.comments = comments!
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                        self.handleResponses.displayError(title: response!.title, message: response!.message)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

**commentFunctions**

```
func loadCommentsForPost(id: Int, completion: @escaping ((ActionResult?), [PostComment]?)->()){

        // downloading the data and then

        let comments : [PostComment] = ...

        // Succesful
        return completion((ActionResult(success: 1, title: responseTitle, message: responseMessage)), comments)

    }
```

Comment: Related: [Swift optional binding with tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991378/swift-optional-binding-with-tuples).

Comment: Unrelated, in `loadCommentsForPost`, that `return` statement doesn't make sense. You can remove the `return` keyword and just call `completion`. Also, in the closure where you call `loadComments`, what do you want to do if either `response` or `comments` was `nil`? Do nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in the line:

```
if let (response, comments) = (response, comments ) {
```

What you are basically doing is creating a new non optional tuple on the right hand side of the assignment (with two optional components), so the compilator complains that you can't use `if let` with a non optional type.

You can in fact consider that the tuple return by loadCommentsForPost is already "split" in the arguments of the callback, so you can handle `response` and `comments` separately.

```
postComments.loadCommentForPost(id: postId) { response, comments in
    if let response = response, let comments = comments {
       if response.success == 1 {
       ...
```